# View split left/right for nautilus home directory in Ubuntu18.04 LTS

Tags: nautilus, 18.04

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I used to drag home directory window to left or right and that window would then automatically adjust to the half of the screen ( this is called view split left or right ) . In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS this does indeed happen with all windows , but it does not happen with the home directory window . I have even tried the keyboard shortcut for view split left or right for home directory and is not working while it works for all other windows .
**Does anyone know how to view split left or right in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for home directory window?**

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I think it's a nautilus issue

Comment: It works for me with every folder, including the home directory.

Comment: If I drag the home directory window on the top edge it fully expands though . I have even reinstalled nautilus using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data` and restarted the laptop , but nothing changed .

Answer (score 0):

That's because of nautilus minimum wide that doesn't fits split view. For example if you remove nautilus sidebar or change the display scale it will allow to split left/right. Don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Settings->Dock and I enabled the option Auto-hide the Dock . When Auto-hide the Dock is On then view split left/right is working for the nautilus home directory , but when it is Off , it does not work . That solution at least works for me . I have no clue if that is a bug of Ubuntu 18.04 lts or if I messed something with some programms.